# How to convert to 16 bit pixel format for use in OpenGL ES 2.0 when reading frames from a video (AV Foundation)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, avfoundation, neon

I'm using **OpenGL** to do some image processing on each frame of a 1280x720 quicktime video. The frames are then read back and a new video is created from these. The problem is the large amount of data that needs to be transfered to and from **OpenGL** (using **glTexImage2D** and **glReadPixels**), resulting in a very slow process.

Currently, I'm using **kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA** as the pixel format for my **AVAssetReaderTrackOutput** instance. To decrease time consumption, I would like to use a 16 bit pixel format instead. Unfortunately, changing to such a format gives me empty frames when calling **AVAssetReaderTrackOutput's copyNextSampleBuffer** method. Does anyone have experience with using a 16 bit pixel format in AV Foundation?

If I can't get AV Foundation to change the format for me, I suppose I could convert from 32 bit to 16 bit "manually", maybe using NEON instructions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A further revision, and this is now community wiki because I've made so many errors in answering this question alone that it makes sense.

Although CoreGraphics would prima facie be able to do a 32bit to 16bit conversion for you using something like the following code, it instead reports that "4 integer bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast" is an unsupported parameter combination. So it seems that CoreGraphics can't internally comprehend 4 bits/channel images.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, width*height*4, NULL);
CGImageRef inputImage = CGImageCreate(  width, height,
                                        8, 32, width*4, 
                                        colourSpace, 
                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big,
                                        dataProvider,
                                        NULL, NO,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

unsigned char *outputImage = (unsigned char *)malloc(width*height*2);
CGContextRef targetContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( outputImage,
                                                    width, height,
                                                    4, width*2,
                                                    colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGContextDrawImage(targetContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), inputImage);

/* uplopad outputImage to OpenGL here! */

CGContextRelease(targetContext);
CGImageRelease(inputImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
free(outputImage);
```

However, per the documentation:

> Supported pixel formats are
>   kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
>   kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
>   and kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, except
>   on iPhone 3G, where the supported
>   pixel formats are
>   kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8 and
>   kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA.

So for reducing the size of what you receive, you could switch to a YCbCr colour space. As the buffers come back biplanar (ie, all y components for the entire image, then all Cb and Cr components as a separate block), you can upload them as two individual textures to OpenGL and recombine in a shader, assuming you're happy limiting yourself to the 3GS and above, and can afford to spend 2 texture units of the 8 that are available on SGX iOS devices.

YCbCr is a colour space that represents colour as brightness (the Y) and colour (the CbCr) separately. It's been shown empirically that the colour channel can be sampled at a lower frequency than the brightness without anybody being able to tell. The '420' part of the pixel format describes how many Cb and Cr components you get for each 4 Y components — essentially it's telling you that you get one sample of Cb and one of Cr for every four samples of Y. Hence you have a total of six bytes to describe four pixels, for 12 bits/pixel rather than 24 bits/pixel in RGB. That saves you 50% of your storage.

For GL purposes you've potentially incurred an extra cost because it's two uploads rather than one. You're also going to need to use three varyings if you want to avoid dependent texture reads, and I think the SGX is limited to eight of those.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean I can supply 32 bit pixel data to glTexImage2D, and it will convert to 16 bit by itself? If that is the case, then which parameters must be changed? My call looks like glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer));

Comment: Actually, it would be 2 textures. 1 texture for Y plane (GL_LUMINANCE) and the other one for UV plane (GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA). And that's how you you get planes: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0); CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);

Comment: @Alex: quite right; that's what I should have inferred from "biplanar". @Gus: the GL_RGBA tells OpenGL what format to use internally, the GL_BGRA tells it what format you're supplying in. So switch the GL_RGBA to the format you want.

Comment: Oh, extra: normally format and internalformat have to be the same in ES, but GL_BGRA is an extension that relaxes the rule. Supposing my memory of how the rule is relaxed is false, the quickest way to convert would probably be to get CoreGraphics to do it for you.

Comment: @Tommy, @Alex: Thanks for helping. @Tommy: I'm not sure what to switch to. The OpenGL ES reference says that internalformat (the third parameter) "must be one of the following symbolic constants: GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA". It does not say anything about the number of bits?

Comment: @Gus: no, I'm in the wrong, I was being a total idiot. Hang on, I'll edit my answer to say something completely different but useful.

Comment: @Tommy: Ok, I'll look into the CoreGraphics methods you mentioned. I'm still confused about how YCbCr comes into all this, though.

Comment: @Tommy: I've searched for examples, but I can't find one doing what you are describing. The closest thing I found was Apple's own Texture2D class (from the CrashLanding example), but it seems like they do a manual conversion from 32 bit to 16 bit...

Comment: @GUS: on YCbCr, the total number of bytes to describe a 420 YCbCr frame is half that to describe the same frame in RGB because colour and luminance signals are split and colour is sampled at a lower frequency. Broadcast television does exactly the same thing. You can write a shader fairly easily to convert to RGB from YCbCr so you end up sending only 50% as much data to OpenGL without reducing pixel resolution or perceptual quality. On CoreGraphics: I'm writing some quick test code now, my comments were made directly from the spec. Possibly 4 bit components aren't supported, we'll see...

Comment: @Tommy, @Alex: Ok, so I managed to upload the Y and UV planes to two different textures, using the kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange pixel format. My plan was to process the planes separately (two different framebuffers). However, since glReadPixels does not accept formats GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, I have no effective way to get the data back from the GPU. Of course I can read the full RGB or RGBA data and throw away the information I do not need, but I doubt this will be faster than my original approach...

Comment: If you want to process entirely in YUV on the GPU, then download again in YUV then it's probably easiest just to write output so that .r = y, .g = u, .b = v, then download as though it were still RGB. Otherwise, if you need to convert then you'll just have to work around the output from the GPU being in a different form than the input — if that's acceptable?

Comment: @Tommy: Setting .r = y, .g = u, .b = v still requires me to download a full size 1280 * 720 * 4 byte image, and then throw away unnecessary data. Maybe one can use a smaller texture and utilize the R-, G-, B- and alpha-channels in some smart way. A 1280x180 texture would be enough for the Y plane, for example. Too bad I can't find any examples on image processing using YCbCr. Thanks for helping out, though.

Comment: But you'v still saved 50% on upload, so you're 25% better off overall even with an RGB download. I guess if you're able to stay in YUV then the best you can do is expand to 422 on the GPU and write r=y1, g=u, b=y2, a=u, to output four bytes for every two pixels rather than six, cutting a third off what you need to download for a roughly 42% saving on both transfers added together. Also, YUV is a linear combination of RGB (and vice versa) so distributive and associative rules mean that most RGB algorithms work directly on YUV too.